# Dynamic calculation in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to do a dynamic calculation in postgres

as following

```
drop table if exists calculation_t;
create table calculation_t(
Id serial,
calculation_logic varchar(50))
```

Inserted a calculation logic :

```
insert into calculation_t(calculation_logic)
values ('$1-$2')
```

checking the calculation by providing dynamic numbers 2,1

```
select (2,1,calculation_logic::numeric) from calculation_t
```

throws an error : "ERROR:  Can't serialize transient record types"

I am expecting to get the result
of `'1' (because my calculation logic is $2-$1 from table caculation_t table for id 1, its 2-1)` by doing the select

```
select (2,1,calculation_logic::numeric) from calculation_t
```

Also tried :

```
select replace(replace(calculation_logic, '$1', 2),'$2',1) from calculation_t

result : 
"2-1"
But I needed 2-1 actual value from subtraction instead, that is 1
```

Comment: It is very unclear what it is that you're trying to do. Can you explain the problem in more detail including the expected result?

Comment: @hgmnz I have edited my post to make my question more clear. Could you please have a look at it now. Thanks!

Comment: You can't just put a piece of maths in a column, and expect the database to calculate it for you; you need to somewhere tell it "execute this statement". Perhaps what you actually need is a [user-defined function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc.html)?

Comment: No idea how you're getting that error, though; I just get `invalid input syntax for type numeric: "$1-$2"`, [as shown in this SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc697/1). Note that you don't want the brackets in your `select` statement; they'll turn the result into a "record", which I very much doubt is your intention.

Comment: Here is a demo of an extremely simple user-defined function; I'm not sure what you actually need to do, so this doesn't really feel like an answer: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1c84/2